# Creating a respring button in a preference bundle on ios 9 with theos?

Tags: ios9, jailbreak, theos, tweak

So im trying to add a respring button in my preference bundle but I cant figure it out. I know you use to be able to use the system command but now cause the settings app is in a sandbox you cant..

Could someone show me how to do it? thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add any sort of buttons you want and customize it as you want.

In code you can call:

```
system("killall SpringBoard");
```

And the SpringBoard will restart. I use it in my tweak and it works fine in iOS 9 and below.